# Value disappearing outside of while loop, even though saving to a malloc variable

Tags: c

I've created a struct called `Utype` that contains different variables.
If I want `t` then I will call `Utype->t`.

Now, I'm using `fgets` to retrieve data from an input file.

**The code is**:

```
#include "read_file.h"

int read_file(int argc, char* argv[], Utype* u_coarse){
    int i;
    int num_length = 1024;
    FILE *input_file;
    char buffer[num_length];
    char *end_of_file;
    char *lines = NULL;
    char *lines_temp;
    int  num_time_segments=0;
    double testest=0;

    for (i=0; i<num_length; i++){
        buffer[i]=' ';
    }
    input_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    end_of_file = fgets(buffer, num_length, input_file);
    while (end_of_file != NULL){

        if (end_of_file[0]!= '\n' && end_of_file[0]!='%'){
            lines = strtok(end_of_file, "=");
            if (lines[strlen(lines)-1] == ' '){
                lines[strlen(lines)-1] = '\0';
            }
            lines_temp = strtok(NULL, "=");
            if (lines_temp[0] == ' '){
                for (i=1; i<strlen(lines_temp); i++){
                    lines_temp[i-1] = lines_temp[i];
                }
                lines_temp[strlen(lines_temp)-2] = '\0';
            }else{
                lines_temp[strlen(lines_temp)-1] = '\0';
            }
            if (strcmp(lines, "T") == 0){
                u_coarse->ultimateT = atof(lines_temp);
            }
        //  printf("%g\n", testest);                                                                                                                           
        }

    }
//  printf("%g\n", testest);                                                                                                                                   
//  u_coarse->burn_time = testest;                                                                                                                             

    fclose(input_file);

    return num_time_segments;
```

After I call this `read_file` function, I try to print

```
u_coarse->ultimateT
```

But it says

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
```

when I use Valgrind. I've been trying to figure out why it's giving me this memory error for a while now. Any help will be much appreciated.

**Edit May 31, 2015**:

Thank you all for your input. I'm attaching the adjusted code that I did with improvements. I still get the same error as before. Valgrind says:

```
==6485== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6485== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6485== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6485== Command: ../bin/main.x ../ ../example_input.inp
==6485== 
==6485== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6485==    at 0x3BFE249CF0: __printf_fp (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==6485==    by 0x3BFE24589F: vfprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==6485==    by 0x3BFE24F189: printf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==6485==    by 0x406CF1: main (main.c:23)
```

where:

```
main.c:23
```

is where I'm printing out :

```
u_coarse->ultimateT
```

**Edited Code**:

```
#include "read_file.h"

int read_file(int argc, char* argv[], Utype* u_coarse){

    int i;
    int num_length = 1024;
    FILE *input_file;
    char buffer[num_length];
    char *current_line;
    char *lines = NULL;
    char *lines_temp;
    int  num_time_segments=0;
    size_t length;
    size_t length_temp;

    memset(buffer, ' ', sizeof(buffer) -1);
    buffer[sizeof(buffer) - 1] = '\0';
    input_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (input_file == NULL){
        perror("Error");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE);
    }else{
        while ( current_line =  fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), input_file)){
            if (current_line[0]!= '\n' && current_line[0]!='%'){
                lines = strtok(current_line, "=");
                if (lines == NULL){
                    perror("Error");
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }
                length = strlen(lines);
                if (lines[length-1] == ' '){
                    lines[length-1] = '\0';
                }
                lines_temp = strtok(NULL, "=");
                if (lines_temp == NULL){
                    perror("Error");
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }
                length_temp = strlen(lines_temp);
                if (lines_temp[0] == ' '){
                    memmove(lines_temp, lines_temp +1, length_temp);
                }else{
                    lines_temp[length_temp-1] = '\0';
                }
                if (strcmp(lines, "T") == 0){
                    u_coarse->ultimateT = atof(lines_temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return num_time_segments;
}
```

**My main.c file is**:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Utype *u_coarse = (Utype*)malloc(sizeof(Utype));                         

    int num_time_segments = read_file(argc, argv, u_coarse);
    printf("%g\n", u_coarse->ultimateT);
```

**My struct is**:

```
typedef struct {
     double ultimateT;
}Utype;
```

Sorry, I've been trying not to show too much since this is for research.

Comment: valgrind can tell you the line number where the problem occurs. Also, don't call `strlen()` so many times, it iterates through the bytes to find the terminating `nul`.

Comment: yes, valgrind tells me there's a problem when I print u_coarse->ultimateT in the main.c that I have.

Comment: You have to post the calling code.

Comment: You really should store the value of `strlen()` your code has to be very slow as it is.

Comment: when calling strtok(), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when calling fopen(), always check (!=NULL) the returned value.  Suggest, if NULL, call perror() then exit( EXIT_FAILURE )

Comment: the 'end_of_file' variable can be eliminated, use 'buffer' instead.

Comment: these two lines: 'end_of_file = fgets(buffer, num_length, input_file);
    while (end_of_file != NULL){'  would be much better (and clearer) written as: 'while( fgets(buffer, sizeof( buffer ), input_file) )'

Comment: Sure would be nice to see a complete example.  As far as we know you're passing uninitialized pointers into the function.  Your valgrind error points to a line you didn't show us.

Comment: I understand. I added an example of my main.c and how I constructed the struct Utype.

Comment: The `ultimateT` value in your struct will be uninitialized unless it is assigned to in the body of the `if (strcmp(lines, "T") == 0)` statement.  Are you positive that assignment is happening?  You could try setting a breakpoint on that line or adding a printf there to show that the code was executed.  It seems like stepping through the code and examining those strings would be quite helpful.

Comment: Yes it is happening. If I printf ultimateT within that loop it prints. If I try to print outside of the while loop, I get the error from valgrind.

Comment: It looks like I was using a faulty version of valgrind or something... so this has been solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has several problems

1. You never check if `strtok()` failed or not, which can cause valgrind to report what it is reporting, or something else since it causes undefined behavior.
2. You use `strlen()` very wrong, `strlen()` loops through the string which means that in each iteration you are looping the same number of times. You must store the value and use the stored value, it's not only more efficient, it also makes your code prettier.
3. The loop never ends, because you don't reassign `end_of_file` which is by the way the worse name for that variable, you should do it like this

   ```
   while (current_line = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), input_file)) ...
   ```
4. You are filling the `buffer` array with a manually written loop when you can use [`memset()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html)

   ```
   memset(buffer, ' ', sizeof(buffer) - 1);
   buffer[sizeof(buffer) - 1] = '\0';
   ```

   would do a better job, syntactically and also it would be more efficient, and also would `nul` terminate `buffer`, which you didn't do.
5. You never check if `fopen()` succeded, which would lead to undefined behavior too, you must check that every function call worked as expected, most of them return special values or set special variables to indicate when a problem happens, failing to check for errors makes your code very unstable and if I was your boss I would fire you. Don't take it wrong, I am saying this because if you follow my advice you will write more robust code, and you will have way less problems.
6. This

   ```
   for (i = 1 ; i < strlen(lines_temp) ; i++)
    {
       lines_temp[i - 1] = lines_temp[i];
    }
   lines_temp[strlen(lines_temp) - 2] = '\0';
   ```

   is bad for several reasons

   1. You should not loop by yourself, use [`memmove()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html) instead.

      ```
      size_t length = strlen(lines_temp);
      memmove(lines_temp, lines_temp + 1, length);
      ```
   2. If you write the loop by yourself, the efficient way would be

      ```
      for (i = 1 ; lines_temp[i] != 0 ; i++)
       {
          lines_temp[i - 1] = lines_temp[i];
       }
      lines_temp[i - 1] = '\0';
      ```

Comment: k thank you for your response. Let me try to understand and implement your suggestions. I really appreciate your help and will get back to you.

Comment: For memmove, why isn't it

        `memmove(lines_temp, lines_temp + 1, length-1);` ?

Comment: Because you also want to copy the `nul` terminator.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've attached the adjusted code, but I still get the same problems.

Comment: Looks like I was using a faulty/ older version of valgrind or something. Thanks for your help. Your advice and critiques is greatly appreciated.